# prize wheel line break

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

How to add line breaks to text of prize wheel, to fit text into the colored triangles?

I tried `</br>` and /n/r but it didn't work
How can I fix it

```html
<div id="wheelOfFortune">
    <canvas id="wheel" width="1200" height="1200"></canvas>
    <div id="spin">SPIN asd asd asd as dasd as dasd asd asd as d</div>
</div>

<script>

    const sectors = [
        {color: "#f82", label: "Who is your hero?"},
        {color: "#0bf", label: "If you could live anywhere, where would it be?"},
        {color: "#fb0", label: "What is your biggest fear?"},
        {color: "#0fb", label: "What is your favorite family vacation?"},
        {color: "#b0f", label: "What would you change about yourself if you could?"},
        {color: "#f0b", label: "What really makes you angry?"},
        {color: "#bf0", label: "What motivates you to work hard?"},
        {color: "#f0b", label: "What is your favorite thing about your career?"},
        {color: "#0fb", label: "What is your biggest complaint about your job?"},
    ];

    // Generate random float in range min-max:
    const rand = (m, M) => Math.random() * (M - m) + m;

    const tot = sectors.length;
    const elSpin = document.querySelector("#spin");
    const ctx = document.querySelector("#wheel").getContext`2d`;
    const dia = ctx.canvas.width;
    const rad = dia / 2;
    const PI = Math.PI;
    const TAU = 2 * PI;
    const arc = TAU / sectors.length;
    const friction = 0.991;  // 0.995=soft, 0.99=mid, 0.98=hard
    const angVelMin = 0.002; // Below that number will be treated as a stop
    let angVelMax = 0; // Random ang.vel. to acceletare to
    let angVel = 0;    // Current angular velocity
    let ang = 0;       // Angle rotation in radians
    let isSpinning = false;
    let isAccelerating = false;

    //* Get index of current sector */
    const getIndex = () => Math.floor(tot - ang / TAU * tot) % tot;

    //* Draw sectors and prizes texts to canvas */
    const drawSector = (sector, i) => {
        const ang = arc * i;
        ctx.save();
// COLOR
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = sector.color;
        ctx.moveTo(rad, rad);
        ctx.arc(rad, rad, rad, ang, ang + arc);
        ctx.lineTo(rad, rad);
        ctx.fill();
// TEXT
        ctx.translate(rad, rad);
        ctx.rotate(ang + arc / 2);
        ctx.textAlign = "right";
        ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
        ctx.font = "bold 30px sans-serif";
        ctx.fillText(sector.label, rad - 10, 10);
//
        ctx.restore();
    };

    //* CSS rotate CANVAS Element */
    const rotate = () => {
        const sector = sectors[getIndex()];
        ctx.canvas.style.transform = `rotate(${ang - PI / 2}rad)`;
        elSpin.textContent = !angVel ? "SPIN" : sector.label;
        elSpin.style.background = sector.color;
    };

    const frame = () => {

        if (!isSpinning) return;

        if (angVel >= angVelMax) isAccelerating = false;

// Accelerate
        if (isAccelerating) {
            angVel ||= angVelMin; // Initial velocity kick
            angVel *= 1.06; // Accelerate
        }

// Decelerate
        else {
            isAccelerating = false;
            angVel *= friction; // Decelerate by friction

// SPIN END:
            if (angVel < angVelMin) {
                isSpinning = false;
                angVel = 0;
            }
        }

        ang += angVel; // Update angle
        ang %= TAU;    // Normalize angle
        rotate();      // CSS rotate!
    };

    const engine = () => {
        frame();
        requestAnimationFrame(engine)
    };

    elSpin.addEventListener("click", () => {
        if (isSpinning) return;
        isSpinning = true;
        isAccelerating = true;
        angVelMax = rand(0.25, 0.40);
    });

    // INIT!
    sectors.forEach(drawSector);
    rotate(); // Initial rotation
    engine(); // Start engine!

</script>

<style type="text/css">
    #wheelOfFortune {
        display: inline-flex;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    #wheel {
        display: block;
    }

    #spin {
        font: 1.5rem/0 sans-serif;
        user-select: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        width: 30%;
        height: 30%;
        margin: -15%;
        background: #fff;
        color: #fff;
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 8px currentColor, 0 0px 15px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
        border-radius: 50%;
        transition: 0.8s;
    }

    #spin::after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: -17px;
        border: 10px solid transparent;
        border-bottom-color: currentColor;
        border-top: none;
    }

</style>
```

Comment: Why not use an SVG instead of a canvas?

Comment: how can I use it

Answer (score 0):

Here is an SVG example to get you started. If it were me, I'd create the svg in inkscape (free download). This would make it easier to play around with the text size and positioning.

Because it's a native dom element you can apply css transforms/animations to do your spinning for you. With your canvas solution you are having to compute the points and calculate where the text should go.

If you insist on using a `canvas` element, then you would need to ise [measureText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/measureText) to get the text metrics of the text to determine where to word-wrap and also then measure the final height to centre the text block.

```html
<svg version="1.1" width="579" height="579" viewBox="0 0 579 579">
    <defs></defs>
    <g transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)" opacity="1">
        <g transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 289.5 289.5)" opacity="1">
            <path transform="matrix(-0.5 -0.867 0.866 -0.5 0 0)" d="M 220.019 0 C 220.019 0 220.046 2.668 219.909 6.98 C 219.84 9.136 219.713 11.801 219.577 13.954 C 219.44 16.107 219.228 18.766 219.023 20.914 C 218.818 23.061 218.522 25.713 218.249 27.852 C 217.976 29.992 217.597 32.633 217.256 34.763 C 216.915 36.893 216.452 39.52 216.043 41.639 C 215.635 43.757 215.089 46.368 214.614 48.472 C 214.138 50.576 213.509 53.169 212.968 55.257 C 212.426 57.345 211.715 59.917 211.107 61.986 C 210.499 64.056 209.707 66.604 209.034 68.653 C 208.361 70.702 207.488 73.224 206.751 75.251 C 206.013 77.278 205.061 79.77 204.259 81.773 C 203.457 83.775 202.427 86.236 201.562 88.212 C 200.697 90.188 199.588 92.615 198.661 94.563 C 197.734 96.511 196.549 98.901 195.561 100.818 C 194.573 102.736 193.313 105.088 192.264 106.973 C 191.215 108.857 189.881 111.168 188.773 113.019 C 187.665 114.87 186.258 117.137 185.092 118.951 C 183.926 120.766 182.448 122.987 181.225 124.764 C 180.002 126.541 178.454 128.714 177.175 130.451 C 175.896 132.188 174.28 134.311 172.947 136.007 C 171.613 137.702 169.931 139.773 168.545 141.426 C 167.158 143.078 165.411 145.094 163.973 146.702 C 162.534 148.31 160.724 150.27 159.235 151.831 C 157.747 153.392 155.875 155.293 154.338 156.806 C 152.801 158.32 150.87 160.161 149.285 161.624 C 147.701 163.088 145.712 164.867 144.082 166.28 C 142.452 167.692 140.408 169.407 138.734 170.767 C 137.06 172.127 134.962 173.777 133.246 175.083 C 131.529 176.389 129.381 177.971 127.624 179.223 C 125.867 180.474 123.669 181.987 121.873 183.182 C 120.077 184.376 117.833 185.819 116 186.956 C 114.167 188.093 111.878 189.464 110.01 190.542 L 0 0 L 220.019 0 Z " fill="#f7d046" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="1" fill-opacity="1" class="" visibility="visible" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="4"></path>
            <text transform="matrix(0 -1 1 0 0 -189.218)" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14pt" line-height="17" text-anchor="end" dominant-baseline="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" font-style="normal" font-weight="500" text-decoration="none" fill="#fff" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" class="" visibility="visible">
                <tspan x="0" dy="-1.0em">If you could live</tspan>
                <tspan x="0" dy="1.2em">anywhere, where</tspan>
                <tspan x="0" dy="1.2em">would it be?</tspan>
            </text>
            <path transform="matrix(0.5 -0.867 0.866 0.5 0 0)" d="M 220.019 0 C 220.019 0 220.046 2.668 219.909 6.98 C 219.84 9.136 219.713 11.801 219.577 13.954 C 219.44 16.107 219.228 18.766 219.023 20.914 C 218.818 23.061 218.522 25.713 218.249 27.852 C 217.976 29.992 217.597 32.633 217.256 34.763 C 216.915 36.893 216.452 39.52 216.043 41.639 C 215.635 43.757 215.089 46.368 214.614 48.472 C 214.138 50.576 213.509 53.169 212.968 55.257 C 212.426 57.345 211.715 59.917 211.107 61.986 C 210.499 64.056 209.707 66.604 209.034 68.653 C 208.361 70.702 207.488 73.224 206.751 75.251 C 206.013 77.278 205.061 79.77 204.259 81.773 C 203.457 83.775 202.427 86.236 201.562 88.212 C 200.697 90.188 199.588 92.615 198.661 94.563 C 197.734 96.511 196.549 98.901 195.561 100.818 C 194.573 102.736 193.313 105.088 192.264 106.973 C 191.215 108.857 189.881 111.168 188.773 113.019 C 187.665 114.87 186.258 117.137 185.092 118.951 C 183.926 120.766 182.448 122.987 181.225 124.764 C 180.002 126.541 178.454 128.714 177.175 130.451 C 175.896 132.188 174.28 134.311 172.947 136.007 C 171.613 137.702 169.931 139.773 168.545 141.426 C 167.158 143.078 165.411 145.094 163.973 146.702 C 162.534 148.31 160.724 150.27 159.235 151.831 C 157.747 153.392 155.875 155.293 154.338 156.806 C 152.801 158.32 150.87 160.161 149.285 161.624 C 147.701 163.088 145.712 164.867 144.082 166.28 C 142.452 167.692 140.408 169.407 138.734 170.767 C 137.06 172.127 134.962 173.777 133.246 175.083 C 131.529 176.389 129.381 177.971 127.624 179.223 C 125.867 180.474 123.669 181.987 121.873 183.182 C 120.077 184.376 117.833 185.819 116 186.956 C 114.167 188.093 111.878 189.464 110.01 190.542 L 0 0 L 220.019 0 Z " fill="#ff4c5a" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="1" fill-opacity="1" class="" visibility="visible" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="4"></path>
            <text transform="matrix(0.866 -0.5 0.5 0.866 163.866 -94.609)" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14pt" line-height="17" text-anchor="end" dominant-baseline="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" font-style="normal" font-weight="500" text-decoration="none" fill="#fff" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" class="" visibility="visible">
                <tspan x="0" dy="-1.0em">If you could live</tspan>
                <tspan x="0" dy="1.2em">anywhere, where</tspan>
                <tspan x="0" dy="1.2em">would it be?</tspan>
            </text>
            <path transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)" d="M 220.019 0 C 220.019 0 220.046 2.668 219.909 6.98 C 219.84 9.136 219.713 11.801 219.577 13.954 C 219.44 16.107 219.228 18.766 219.023 20.914 C 218.818 23.061 218.522 25.713 218.249 27.852 C 217.976 29.992 217.597 32.633 217.256 34.763 C 216.915 36.893 216.452 39.52 216.043 41.639 C 215.635 43.757 215.089 46.368 214.614 48.472 C 214.138 50.576 213.509 53.169 212.968 55.257 C 212.426 57.345 211.715 59.917 211.107 61.986 C 210.499 64.056 209.707 66.604 209.034 68.653 C 208.361 70.702 207.488 73.224 206.751 75.251 C 206.013 77.278 205.061 79.77 204.259 81.773 C 203.457 83.775 202.427 86.236 201.562 88.212 C 200.697 90.188 199.588 92.615 198.661 94.563 C 197.734 96.511 196.549 98.901 195.561 100.818 C 194.573 102.736 193.313 105.088 192.264 106.973 C 191.215 108.857 189.881 111.168 188.773 113.019 C 187.665 114.87 186.258 117.137 185.092 118.951 C 183.926 120.766 182.448 122.987 181.225 124.764 C 180.002 126.541 178.454 128.714 177.175 130.451 C 175.896 132.188 174.28 134.311 172.947 136.007 C 171.613 137.702 169.931 139.773 168.545 141.426 C 167.158 143.078 165.411 145.094 163.973 146.702 C 162.534 148.31 160.724 150.27 159.235 151.831 C 157.747 153.392 155.875 155.293 154.338 156.806 C 152.801 158.32 150.87 160.161 149.285 161.624 C 147.701 163.088 145.712 164.867 144.082 166.28 C 142.452 167.692 140.408 169.407 138.734 170.767 C 137.06 172.127 134.962 173.777 133.246 175.083 C 131.529 176.389 129.381 177.971 127.624 179.223 C 125.867 180.474 123.669 181.987 121.873 183.182 C 120.077 184.376 117.833 185.819 116 186.956 C 114.167 188.093 111.878 189.464 110.01 190.542 L 0 0 L 220.019 0 Z " fill="#f08cba" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="1" fill-opacity="1" class="" visibility="visible" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="4"></path>
            <text transform="matrix(0.866 0.5 -0.5 0.866 163.866 94.608)" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14pt" line-height="17" text-anchor="end" dominant-baseline="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" font-style="normal" font-weight="500" text-decoration="none" fill="#fff" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" class="" visibility="visible">
                <tspan x="0" dy="-1.0em">If you could live</tspan>
                <tspan x="0" dy="1.2em">anywhere, where</tspan>
                <tspan x="0" dy="1.2em">would it be?</tspan>
            </text>
            <path transform="matrix(0.5 0.866 -0.867 0.5 0 0)" d="M 220.019 0 C 220.019 0 220.046 2.668 219.909 6.98 C 219.84 9.136 219.713 11.801 219.577 13.954 C 219.44 16.107 219.228 18.766 219.023 20.914 C 218.818 23.061 218.522 25.713 218.249 27.852 C 217.976 29.992 217.597 32.633 217.256 34.763 C 216.915 36.893 216.452 39.52 216.043 41.639 C 215.635 43.757 215.089 46.368 214.614 48.472 C 214.138 50.576 213.509 53.169 212.968 55.257 C 212.426 57.345 211.715 59.917 211.107 61.986 C 210.499 64.056 209.707 66.604 209.034 68.653 C 208.361 70.702 207.488 73.224 206.751 75.251 C 206.013 77.278 205.061 79.77 204.259 81.773 C 203.457 83.775 202.427 86.236 201.562 88.212 C 200.697 90.188 199.588 92.615 198.661 94.563 C 197.734 96.511 196.549 98.901 195.561 100.818 C 194.573 102.736 193.313 105.088 192.264 106.973 C 191.215 108.857 189.881 111.168 188.773 113.019 C 187.665 114.87 186.258 117.137 185.092 118.951 C 183.926 120.766 182.448 122.987 181.225 124.764 C 180.002 126.541 178.454 128.714 177.175 130.451 C 175.896 132.188 174.28 134.311 172.947 136.007 C 171.613 137.702 169.931 139.773 168.545 141.426 C 167.158 143.078 165.411 145.094 163.973 146.702 C 162.534 148.31 160.724 150.27 159.235 151.831 C 157.747 153.392 155.875 155.293 154.338 156.806 C 152.801 158.32 150.87 160.161 149.285 161.624 C 147.701 163.088 145.712 164.867 144.082 166.28 C 142.452 167.692 140.408 169.407 138.734 170.767 C 137.06 172.127 134.962 173.777 133.246 175.083 C 131.529 176.389 129.381 177.971 127.624 179.223 C 125.867 180.474 123.669 181.987 121.873 183.182 C 120.077 184.376 117.833 185.819 116 186.956 C 114.167 188.093 111.878 189.464 110.01 190.542 L 0 0 L 220.019 0 Z " fill="#49c4d2" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="1" fill-opacity="1" class="" visibility="visible" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="4"></path>
            <text transform="matrix(0 1 -1 0 0 189.217)" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14pt" line-height="17" text-anchor="end" dominant-baseline="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" font-style="normal" font-weight="500" text-decoration="none" fill="#fff" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" class="" visibility="visible">
                <tspan x="0" dy="-1.0em">If you could live</tspan>
                <tspan x="0" dy="1.2em">anywhere, where</tspan>
                <tspan x="0" dy="1.2em">would it be?</tspan>
            </text>
            <path transform="matrix(-0.5 0.866 -0.867 -0.5 0 0)" d="M 220.019 0 C 220.019 0 220.046 2.668 219.909 6.98 C 219.84 9.136 219.713 11.801 219.577 13.954 C 219.44 16.107 219.228 18.766 219.023 20.914 C 218.818 23.061 218.522 25.713 218.249 27.852 C 217.976 29.992 217.597 32.633 217.256 34.763 C 216.915 36.893 216.452 39.52 216.043 41.639 C 215.635 43.757 215.089 46.368 214.614 48.472 C 214.138 50.576 213.509 53.169 212.968 55.257 C 212.426 57.345 211.715 59.917 211.107 61.986 C 210.499 64.056 209.707 66.604 209.034 68.653 C 208.361 70.702 207.488 73.224 206.751 75.251 C 206.013 77.278 205.061 79.77 204.259 81.773 C 203.457 83.775 202.427 86.236 201.562 88.212 C 200.697 90.188 199.588 92.615 198.661 94.563 C 197.734 96.511 196.549 98.901 195.561 100.818 C 194.573 102.736 193.313 105.088 192.264 106.973 C 191.215 108.857 189.881 111.168 188.773 113.019 C 187.665 114.87 186.258 117.137 185.092 118.951 C 183.926 120.766 182.448 122.987 181.225 124.764 C 180.002 126.541 178.454 128.714 177.175 130.451 C 175.896 132.188 174.28 134.311 172.947 136.007 C 171.613 137.702 169.931 139.773 168.545 141.426 C 167.158 143.078 165.411 145.094 163.973 146.702 C 162.534 148.31 160.724 150.27 159.235 151.831 C 157.747 153.392 155.875 155.293 154.338 156.806 C 152.801 158.32 150.87 160.161 149.285 161.624 C 147.701 163.088 145.712 164.867 144.082 166.28 C 142.452 167.692 140.408 169.407 138.734 170.767 C 137.06 172.127 134.962 173.777 133.246 175.083 C 131.529 176.389 129.381 177.971 127.624 179.223 C 125.867 180.474 123.669 181.987 121.873 183.182 C 120.077 184.376 117.833 185.819 116 186.956 C 114.167 188.093 111.878 189.464 110.01 190.542 L 0 0 L 220.019 0 Z " fill="#924e84" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="1" fill-opacity="1" class="" visibility="visible" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="4"></path>
            <text transform="matrix(-0.867 0.5 -0.5 -0.867 -163.867 94.608)" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14pt" line-height="17" text-anchor="end" dominant-baseline="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" font-style="normal" font-weight="500" text-decoration="none" fill="#fff" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" class="" visibility="visible">
                <tspan x="0" dy="-1.0em">If you could live</tspan>
                <tspan x="0" dy="1.2em">anywhere, where</tspan>
                <tspan x="0" dy="1.2em">would it be?</tspan>
            </text>
            <path transform="matrix(-1 0 -0.001 -1 0 0)" d="M 220.019 0 C 220.019 0 220.046 2.668 219.909 6.98 C 219.84 9.136 219.713 11.801 219.577 13.954 C 219.44 16.107 219.228 18.766 219.023 20.914 C 218.818 23.061 218.522 25.713 218.249 27.852 C 217.976 29.992 217.597 32.633 217.256 34.763 C 216.915 36.893 216.452 39.52 216.043 41.639 C 215.635 43.757 215.089 46.368 214.614 48.472 C 214.138 50.576 213.509 53.169 212.968 55.257 C 212.426 57.345 211.715 59.917 211.107 61.986 C 210.499 64.056 209.707 66.604 209.034 68.653 C 208.361 70.702 207.488 73.224 206.751 75.251 C 206.013 77.278 205.061 79.77 204.259 81.773 C 203.457 83.775 202.427 86.236 201.562 88.212 C 200.697 90.188 199.588 92.615 198.661 94.563 C 197.734 96.511 196.549 98.901 195.561 100.818 C 194.573 102.736 193.313 105.088 192.264 106.973 C 191.215 108.857 189.881 111.168 188.773 113.019 C 187.665 114.87 186.258 117.137 185.092 118.951 C 183.926 120.766 182.448 122.987 181.225 124.764 C 180.002 126.541 178.454 128.714 177.175 130.451 C 175.896 132.188 174.28 134.311 172.947 136.007 C 171.613 137.702 169.931 139.773 168.545 141.426 C 167.158 143.078 165.411 145.094 163.973 146.702 C 162.534 148.31 160.724 150.27 159.235 151.831 C 157.747 153.392 155.875 155.293 154.338 156.806 C 152.801 158.32 150.87 160.161 149.285 161.624 C 147.701 163.088 145.712 164.867 144.082 166.28 C 142.452 167.692 140.408 169.407 138.734 170.767 C 137.06 172.127 134.962 173.777 133.246 175.083 C 131.529 176.389 129.381 177.971 127.624 179.223 C 125.867 180.474 123.669 181.987 121.873 183.182 C 120.077 184.376 117.833 185.819 116 186.956 C 114.167 188.093 111.878 189.464 110.01 190.542 L 0 0 L 220.019 0 Z " fill="#924e84" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="1" fill-opacity="1" class="" visibility="visible" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="4"></path>
            <text transform="matrix(-0.867 0.5 -0.5 -0.867 -163.867 94.608)" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14pt" line-height="17" text-anchor="end" dominant-baseline="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" font-style="normal" font-weight="500" text-decoration="none" fill="#fff" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" class="" visibility="visible">
                <tspan x="0" dy="-1.0em">If you could live</tspan>
                <tspan x="0" dy="1.2em">anywhere, where</tspan>
                <tspan x="0" dy="1.2em">would it be?</tspan>
            </text>
            <text transform="matrix(-0.867 -0.5 0.5 -0.867 -163.867 -94.609)" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14pt" line-height="17" text-anchor="end" dominant-baseline="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" font-style="normal" font-weight="500" text-decoration="none" fill="#fff" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="1" opacity="1" class="" visibility="visible">
                <tspan x="0" dy="-1.0em">If you could live</tspan>
                <tspan x="0" dy="1.2em">anywhere, where</tspan>
                <tspan x="0" dy="1.2em">would it be?</tspan>
            </text>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```